# problem with NameError when trying to reference a variable

Tags: python

I am having a problem inputting data forma  txt file as a variable into my code. here is currently what I have. I am using python 3.10 if you need the information.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
#import data into variables for use


def ReadInput(diffsolverin):
   file = open(diffsolverin,"r")
   line = file.readline() # rea the first line (remove comments from input)
   tokens = line.split() # this splits the line into chunks of characters separated by spaces
   Nx = int(tokens[0]) # assign the value of the first chunk of characters to Nx after interpreting them as an integer
   Ny = int(tokens[1])
   width = float(tokens[2])
   height = float(tokens[3])
   D = float(tokens[4])
   t = float(tokens[5])
   U_x = float(tokens[6])
   U_y = float(tokens[7])
   S_p = float(tokens[8])
   line = file.readline() # read the second line
   tokens = line.split()
   left_bc_type = int(tokens[0]) #0 is Dirichlet, 1 is Neumann
   right_bc_type = int(tokens[1])
   top_bc_type = int(tokens[2])
   bottom_bc_type = int(tokens[3])
   line = file.readline() # read the third line
   tokens = line.split()
   left_bc_value = float(tokens[0]) 
   right_bc_value = int(tokens[1])
   top_bc_value = int(tokens[2])
   bottom_bc_value = int(tokens[3])

        
        
N = Nx*Ny
L = 1
h = np.float64(L/(N-1))
sigma = np.zeros((N,N))
b = np.zeros(N)
```

the txt. file looks just like below.

```
20 20 1.0 2.0 0.5 0.1 1 4 1
0 0 1 1
0.0 100.0 0.0 0.0
```

When I run the code, I get to N = NxNy and it says, N = NxNy NameError: name 'Nx' is not defined.
any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exactly WHAT is the problem? Please read [ask].

Comment: I get to N = Nx*Ny and it says, N = Nx*Ny NameError: name 'Nx' is not defined

Comment: because you haven't defined it (in the global scope which is where you are trying to access it)

Comment: how did I not define if I didn't define it above by pulling in the numbers from the txt file?

Comment: Because you haven't called `ReadInput` anywhere.

Comment: so how would i go about fixing that?

Comment: because didn't I do Readinput above the variables pulling them in?

Comment: Even if you called it, `Nx` would exist only inside `ReadInput`, which is a function. So either move where you're accessing `Nx` to `ReadInput` or return it from the function.

Comment: You only *defined* `Readinput`, but you're not calling the function.

Comment: also don't do what you are doing, you are way too repetitive in your code, use some loop or sth and add the values to a list or a dictionary via looping instead of _manual labor_ that is extremely prone to some failure

Comment: how do i return it from the function? Are we saying that i just need to define N by keeping it tabbed the same amount with the other portions of the data being retrieved then i can pull that data out by just going N_x=Nx?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying ? I'm not very good at python or coding in general.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `Nx` in the function but that doesn't mean you can access it outside of the function.

You can either `return` `Nx` and `Ny` as follows:

```
def ReadInput(diffsolverin):
    ...
    return Nx, Ny
            
Nx, Ny = ReadInput(diffsolverin)
```

Or you can move `N = Nx*Ny` inside the function:

```
def ReadInput(diffsolverin):
   ...
   bottom_bc_value = int(tokens[3])
   N = Nx*Ny
```

Comment: doing the first portion for the return i am getting this error, Nx, Ny = ReadInput(diffsolverin)
NameError: name 'diffsolverin' is not defined

Comment: I would be willing to use the 2nd method but I would be using a lot of the variables elsewhere in the code and would rather just have them all pulled out.

Comment: @DylanBull Yes, because you haven't defined `diffsolverin`. `diffsolverin` is what you want to pass to the function.

Comment: @DylanBull Then just take the whole code out of the function as you don't call it anyway.

Comment: diffsolverin should be a string variable containing the file name. You have to define it before calling ReadInput. (diffsolverin = "file_name.txt")

Comment: this has confused me so much. I pulled the file in and set all the value based on the .txt file. so now I have to go about defining a txt file?  this is what I don't understand since I already should have brought the data into the code, which obviously I didn't because its not there. Moving past it not being there the return function should return all those variables to the source i want and leave them there for me to grab. which it doesn't so now i have to call upon the file again to get it to work?

Comment: @DylanBull Do you have the txt file that you want to use?

Comment: yes I have it made its called diffsolverin.txt

Comment: @DylanBull Do you want to take the code out of the function or not?

Comment: umm I believe that would be easier.

Comment: @DylanBull Then do that and change `file = open(diffsolverin,"r")` to `file = open("diffsolverin.txt","r")`

Comment: Thank you so much! just for clarification though so I understand why it wasn't working. so someone said something about the source. so because I had it open form the file and saved to a specific source function I couldn't access it in the way I wanted to?

Comment: @DylanBull You can't access variables inside the function from outside the function unless you `return` them. If my answer helped please accept it by clicking the tick next to the answer.